# ADF Custom Components

Tags: java, oracle, jsf, jakarta-ee, oracle-adf

Where is the best place to find custom compnonents? Ideally a repository, as opposed to finding a few here and there. We are currently about to re-design our look and feel UI for about 200 forms and we were hoping to find a lot of custom components... We were told they were everywhere by the pre-sales architect but even a simple [google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=adf+custom+components&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Oracle ADF 11i Faces, you have over 100 Components out of the box (According to the Oracle site even over a 150 Ajax-enabled JSF components). Try using these first (could be better than custom components).

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant: ADF 11g Rich Client Components